# htaccess mod rewrite with multiple query parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can't quite get this redirect right. 
I want to redirect a legacy url
http://www.example.com/product/page.php?item=AB123-AB123&upc=12345678910&c=1234

to

http://www.example.com/product/AB123-AB123

There will be variations of the url. i.e. google anlyatics tracking code or other query parameters. The only portion of the query string I need is item=AB123-AB123. I don't care about anything after that, although it would be nice to carry the remaining query string.
http://www.example.com/product/AB123-AB123?upc=12345678910&c=1234

I have tried as suggested:
RewriteRule ^product/([^/]*)$ /product/page.php?item=$1&upc=12345678910&c=1234 [L]

but I receive a 404 error. I've verified the resulting page is correct and active. i.e. http://www.example.com/product/AB123-AB123

Comment: I'm assuming that in the suggest rewrite, the upc and c parameters need to be a wildcard match of sorts and may be a reason why it's ignoring the rule.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
 RewriteRule ^product/([^/]*)/?$ /product/page.php?item=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Querystrings  automatically get appended to the destination url.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and still received a 404 error. I went to the page it is suppose to redirect to and also received a 404 error. I removed the suggestion from htaccess and the destination page had no 404 error.

Comment: after looking at my error log, I think something else is going on. This is on a subdomain and I think the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Is your htaccess inside root folder?